# How to create entity in Room DB with extend some other class with some fields

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

I have two entity as below in Room DATABASE.

- UserInfo
- UserData

UserInfo is extending UserData but i don't want all fields in UserInfo class.

**UserTable(Super class)**

```
@Entity
public class UserData {

    @PrimaryKey
    private int userId = 0;

    private String prefix = null;   
    private String firstName = null;
    private String middleName = null;
    private String lastName = null;
    private String email = null;

}
```

**UserInfo(Child class)**

```
@Entity
public class UserInfo extends UserData {

    int id;

    //HERE all other fields are created from UserData and i don't want it into UserInfo Table..

}
```

**NOTE : I must to use @Ignore annotation in the UserInfo class ?
I also want to save whole class into SharedPreference but there is problem for duplicate values exists so ,what we can do in this case.**

Answer (score 0):

Your fields in **UserData** class are `private`. It means that you do not access them in **UserInfo** class.